# Group Arithmetic

Tags: lateral-thinking, letter-sequence

A little arithmetic to rock your brain.  Each pair of equations is separate from the others. Within each pair, the variable to be solved for will represent the same thing, however other variables may or (most likely) may not.

**Problem 1**

> K1+K2+D=N
>   D+P+N+T+C=F
>   Solve for D

**Problem 2**

> K+E+C+P+J=Y
>   E+J+G=C
>   Solve for E

**Problem 3**

> G+J+R+P=B
>   P+L+D+J=W
>   Solve for P

This is my first time posting so feedback is welcome.  Also, not sure how to tag it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** Oops, I guess I technically didn't "solve for" the correct things. Changes made below:

**Problem 1**

> Kris + Kurt + Dave = [Nirvana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(band))
>  Dave + Pat + Nate + Taylor + Chris = [Foo Fighters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo_Fighters)
>  $D = Dave\ Grohl$

**Problem 2**

> Keith + Eric + Chris + Paul + Jimmy (or Jeff) = [Yardbirds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Yardbirds)
>  Eric + Jack + Ginger = [Cream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_(band))
>  $E = Eric\ Clapton$

**Problem 3**

> George + John + Ringo + Paul = [Beatles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles)
>  Paul + Linda + Denny + Jimmy = [Wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_McCartney_and_Wings)
>  $P = Paul\ McCartney$

Extra Stuff:

> "Group" in the title, "rock" in the opening sentence of the description... *ta-daaaaa*

Comment: And the asker has become the answerer...